# Get reference to spring bean from @WebService

Tags: java, web-services, spring, cxf

I'm using CXF to generate a web service from wsdl.
The generated web service has the annotation @WebService
How do i get a reference to spring bean from the web service?
All my spring beans are annotated with @Service, and I can access them
in my web application. How do I access them also from my web service?

I've tried the following:

```
public class TestWSImpl implements TestWSSoap{

    @Resource
    public WebServiceContext wsContext;

    @Override
    public String getTest() {

        ServletContext servletContext= (ServletContext) wsContext.getMessageContext().get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);

        ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);

        return "Test";
    }
}
```

But the getWebApplicationContext method returns null

When I replace getWebApplicationContext with getRequiredWebApplicationContext
I get an error message: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks
Alon

Answer (score 1):

If you were using JUnit 4.4 or higher you could inject it using the Spring 2.5 JUnit annotations.  Here's an example.

http://hamletdarcy.blogspot.com/2008/12/autowired-junit-tests-with-spring-25.html

Of course it goes without saying that this approach requires that the web service be running in a web context when the test is started.  Have you done that?

You also might prefer testing WSDL based services using [SOAP UI.](http://www.soapui.org/)

Comment: I don't want to use JUnit for this task, as it not seems to me as the standard way to solve it.
Anyway, I use SOAP UI tool and it's indeed very helpful

Answer (score 0):

It was a long time ago.
I'm looking on my code and I see that I put the following method
that should init the spring:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    JaxWsServerFactoryBean svrFactory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
    svrFactory.setServiceClass(MyWebService.class);
    svrFactory.setAddress("http://address.com");
    svrFactory.setServiceBean(wsHandler);
    svrFactory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
    svrFactory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
    svrFactory.create();
```

}

Please tell me if it solve you problem....